# asp.net MVC + Custom STS for Windows & SQL based mixed authentication (external and internal users)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0, mixed-authentication

I have internal users which I need to authenticate using Windows authentication & other external users which are stored in SQL tables.

I need to be able to authenticate both appropriately based on on the scenario, like,

1. If the internal users open the web app from browser while they are logged in from their network, then just take the windows authentication route, establish the identity and go on.. no login screen.
2. If the external users login from internet, then provide elegant login page and authenticate them with SQL based store. User name format would be email ID.
3. If the internal users logon from internet, then provide then login screen and based on the format in user name (like domain\username, no browser prompt for credentials) and authenticate them with AD.

All this needs to work via a custom STS (wif based), 
how can this be done all together? 
Is there any readily available framework that does it? 
Is there any code/article available on internet?